# Converting base64string to Image type. Image type could not be found?

Tags: c#, image, types, base64, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a `Base64String` back to an `Image`. I have this code set up in my C# console application.

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    // Convert byte[] to Image
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    return image;
}
```

I'm getting an error each time I use the type `Image`. It says:

> The type or namespace name could not be found.

I'm using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Drawing;
```

Am I missing a library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you're writing a *console* application, your project probably won't include a reference to `System.Drawing.dll`, which is the assembly containing [`System.Drawing.Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7e7b2kd.aspx). Just add the assembly reference, and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks ya'll...7 whole more minutes until I can accept an answer. Damn.

Answer (score 1):

In the project window, right click on the references, and choose "Add Reference..."  In the .NET Framework, choose System.Drawing.dll.